# Get python code to persist after IndexError

Tags: python, gzip, urllib, python-multithreading, pyodbc

I am querying an API from a website. The API will be down for maintenance from time to time and also, there may not be data available for querying at times. I have written the code to keep forcing the program to query the API even after an error, however  it doesn't seem to be working.

The following is the code:

```
import threading
import json
import urllib
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import httplib2 as http #External library
import datetime
import pyodbc as db
import os
import gzip
import csv
import shutil
def task():

    #Authentication parameters
    headers = { 'AccountKey' : 'secret',
    'accept' : 'application/json'} #this is by default

    #API parameters
    uri = 'http://somewebsite.com/' #Resource URL
    path = '/something/TrafficIncidents?'

    #Build query string & specify type of API call
    target = urlparse(uri + path)
    print(target.geturl())
    method = 'GET'
    body = ''

    #Get handle to http
    h = http.Http()

    #Obtain results
    response, content = h.request(target.geturl(), method, body, headers)
    api_call_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    filename = "traffic_incidents_" + str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    createHeader = 1
    if os.path.exists(filename + '.csv'):
        csvFile = open(filename + '.csv', 'a')
        createHeader = 0
    else:
        #compress previous day's file
        prev_filename =  "traffic_incidents_" + (datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        if os.path.exists(prev_filename + '.csv'):
            with open(prev_filename + '.csv' , 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open(prev_filename + '.csv.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
                shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
            os.remove(prev_filename + '.csv')

        #create new csv file for writing
        csvFile = open(filename + '.csv', 'w')

    #Parse JSON to print
    jsonObj = json.loads(content)
    print (json.dumps(jsonObj, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

    with open("traffic_incidents.json","w") as outfile:
        #Saving jsonObj["d"]
        json.dump(jsonObj, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)

    for i in range(len(jsonObj["value"])):
        jsonObj["value"][i]["IncidentTime"] = jsonObj["value"][i]["Message"].split(' ',1)[0]
        jsonObj["value"][i]["Message"] = jsonObj["value"][i]["Message"].split(' ',1)[1]
        jsonObj["value"][i]["ApiCallTime"] = api_call_time

    #Save to csv file
    header = jsonObj["value"][0].keys()   

    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvFile,lineterminator='\n')
    if createHeader == 1:
        csvwriter.writerow(header)

    for i in range(len(jsonObj["value"])):
        csvwriter.writerow(jsonObj["value"][i].values())

    csvFile.close()

    t = threading.Timer(120,task)
    t.start()


while True:
    try:
        task()
    except IndexError:
        pass
    else:
        break
```

I get the following error and the program stops:

```
"header = jsonObj["value"][0].keys()
IndexError: list index out of range"
```

I would like the program to keep running even after the IndexError has occured.

How can I edit the code to achieve that?

Comment: Just catch the exception like you did elsewhere in your code. You have to question though that it might be best to write code that checks for the lack of entries in your data and acts accordingly rather than fall by back on exceptions

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with the threading operation. Not sure but I don't know if the calling context is preserved in a way that would use the try/except block. Try removing the threading calls at the bottom of your function, and in your try/except block change the `pass` statement to be `time.sleep(120)` instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want the test at a deeper level in the code. You should really know where you're getting an `IndexError`, and what you want to do about it. For example, if it's that `header = jsonObj["value"][0].keys()`, because sometimes `value` is an empty list, then you want to check that—probably before you open and start writing any files—and just `return`. But meanwhile, you _also_ shouldn't be using threads like this, as Chris Johnson says. Just use a `while True:` loop and a `sleep` call.